# How to draw circles in a rectangle

Tags: html, css

I want to create a rectangle in which there will be several black circles.
Here's some of the ways I tried:
w3school:

```css
.dot {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
```

Doesn't display anything in edge.
Another:

```css
.circle{
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: black;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

That won't display two circles in one line.
I tested a few more versions, but they did not work.
This is an approximate version of what I want to do:

[image]

Comment: Must the circles contain something? otherwise you could use a `&bull;`

Comment: ? A rectangle which contain circles

Comment: btw, both snippets show circles for me. The reason that the last one is not inline is because it's block, you need to give it `display: inline-block;`

Comment: how to put it in a black rectangle?

Comment: They both show in edge if I test it

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qMdWeL You can improve the codepen I did from your code

Comment: What have you tried? Because you've got circles, and wrapping them in a div is *very* basic.

Comment: why do you think / feel that this is a php related question? You haven't posted any code for it or shown relevance. That makes your question be unclear and is misleading to those who follow that tag.

Comment: @Martijn lol, a professional wouldn't ask this question, I'm a beginner.

Comment: @Funk Furty Niner sorry, I saw how to do that with php, but I didn't provide what I tried with php.

Comment: If you can make a circle, you know you started with a rectangle. If you know a rectangle, well you've got what you're looking for. A bit of common sense would've answered your question, regardless of skill level :)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.dot {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.rectangle {
  background: black;
  display: inline-block; /* Makes the rectangle the width of all circles */
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
```

Or:

```css
.dot {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.rectangle {
  background: black;
  width: 116px; /* Limit width for wrapping */
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is a mock up i got working using a list element:

```
<div id="rectangle">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
#rectangle {
      width:500px;
      border:2px solid #000;
      padding:20px;
}
li {
      list-style-type: none;
      display:inline-block;
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      background-color: #bbb;
      border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Working Example: https://codepen.io/FEARtheMoose/pen/vzOBqo?editors=1100#0

Comment: I'll try it in my webserver

Comment: i think that loading issue is something local your end, it works fine here in all my browsers. maybe connection issues?

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like that, and use bootstrap's grid with that.

If you dont want to use Bootstrap, you can just add a `float: left;` inside every Circle's div

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black">
  Rectangle
  <div style="border-radius: 50px; border: 1px solid black">
    Circle
  </div>
  <div style="border-radius: 50px; border: 1px solid black">
    Circle
  </div>
  <div style="border-radius: 50px; border: 1px solid black">
    Circle
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't inline style (specially when TS has already shown to understand classes), it's preferred to upkeep a somewhat nice code practise in answers :) Also, the bootstrap grid is not needed at all and will only add a lot of weight for what 4 css lines can do. Also, a tip; instead of float, try to use `display: inline-block`. It's a bit more sensative (cant have spaces between items), but will give you a lot cleaner code which is easier to make responsive :)

Comment: I'll remember this :) Sorry

Comment: No problem, we're all here to learn. Learning how to formulate a proper answer is one of those things :)